# How to disable Tumblr Photosets

Tags: tumblr

I'd like to disable the tumblr Photoset-function. That means I just want to have one picture on my tumblr-site instead of the "Layout" which is provided by Tumblr. But when the picture is clicked the Lightbox would still open. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the normal photoset function by using the `{block:Photos} {/block:Photos}` block, which renders individually for each image in the set. It is also possible to select a single picture (plenty of themes do it), but I have no idea how you do it (I'm no developer, but I'll wager Javascript or undocumented code is involved), much less whether you can trigger the full lightbox without ever displaying the other images directly.